# Matplotlib: plotting multiple histograms side by side with different colors and different alphas

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple data into a histogram, where each dataset has it's own color and alpha value. I tried this:

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
alphas = [1.0, 0.7, 0.3]
plt.hist([data1, data2, data3], bins = 15, label=['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'], color = colors, alpha = alphas)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
alpha must be numeric or None, not <class 'list'>
```

but I want different alpha values for each histogram. How can I achieve that?

I tried using `zip` as @BigBen suggested in the comments:

```
datas = [data1, data2, data3]
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
alphas = [1.0, 0.7, 0.3]
labels = ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3']
plt.savefig('images/bla.png')
for data, label, color, alpha in zip(datas, labels, colors, alphas):
    plt.hist(data, bins=10, label=label, color=color, alpha=alpha)
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image: overlapping histogram]

But I need something like this, but with different alpha values for different colors:

[image: distinct histogram]

Comment: Use `zip` maybe.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: What is the point of alpha? Are you expecting red to have alpha=1, green with alpha=0.7 and blue with alpha=0.3? Other things can be achieved (I think), but different alphas, I am not aware. Let me know

Comment: yes, that is what I was expecting. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[matplotlib.colors.to_rgba](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.to_rgba.html) is the solution. With it, one can add alpha values to colors.

```
red = matplotlib.colors.to_rgba('red', alpha=1)
green = matplotlib.colors.to_rgba('green', alpha=0.7)
blue = matplotlib.colors.to_rgba('blue', alpha=0.3)
colors = [red, green, blue]

plt.hist([data1, data2, data3], bins = 15, label=['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3'], color = colors)
```

[image]